# resuming app in WP7.1 gets textbox cleared

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I made an App on WP7 that uses the textbox for the user to write into, but when the user goes to other app and returns back using multitasking all the stuff in the textbox just gets erased. (The video of the app is **[HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9Is5QFXmpc)** what I mean is at 1:57)

The app is already in the marketplace, and I don't want to update it with a Mango version so people in NoDo still be able to use it, yet, I still want to solve that problem, what can I do about it?

Comment: are you properly using Tomb stoning in your app?

Comment: Thanks to you and the other answer, I will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the new WP7.1 mango Tombstoning examples and tutorial for absolute beginner to tombstoning.

[Mango WP7.1 Tombstoning](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-13-what.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

you need to persist the textbox value in a setting/file on the device.  You can do this manually by writing lots of code to save and restore the values... or you could use the tombstone helper library which will do it for you:

http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the marketplace now supports versions of apps that support both 7.0 and 7.5. See the announcement at http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/10/18/marketplace-comes-to-china-amp-india-also-improves-search-and-7-0-amp-7-5-app-update-options.aspx

In terms of preserving the content of the textbox see:
[Execution Model Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
and [How to: Preserve and Restore Page State for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967548%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)